# HttpRequest header “X-Forwarded-Proto” missing

Tags: asp.net, http, http-headers, httprequest

We have a load balancer for IIS ASP.NET Web Application which forwards all the `https` requests as `http` . Hence we required the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to identify https.
I'm able to see `X-Forwarded-For` header but not the `Proto`.

I'm checking in `Request.Headers`

Is there something missing or any alternative to know the original request was https ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Forwarded-Proto` header is explicitly set by the Load Balancer through `IRule`. As the `IRule` was not being applied `X-Forwarded-Proto` header was missing.