# Header Appears in IIS Logs But Not In Request.Headers

Tags: c#, iis

Our FWLB is sending an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, which is visible in the IIS logs:

```
#Fields: date time cs-method ... X-Forwarded-For X-Forwarded-Proto
2017-06-05 13:34:35 GET ... 1.2.3.4 http
```

But from C# it is not visible:

```
var output = $"X-Forwarded-Proto is {Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"]} headers are: {string.Join(", ", Request.Headers)}";
```

Output

```
X-Forwarded-Proto is  headers are: Connection=close&Host=1.1.1.1
```

Why is the header not found in C#?

Comment: Does anything show with Request.SeverVariables?
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23220603/5311735?

Comment: @GregHNZ thanks for the suggestion, `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]` is also empty.

Comment: @Evk in my case, I can see that the header has been set by the FWLB as it is in the IIS log. It is just that the ASP.NET MVC application can't find it.